# Add current system date to the file name using Python

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

I'm writing a script to move a file and rename that file with the current system date like 27/08/2014 10-30_po.log.....

```
import shutil
import datetime
import os

def timeStamped(fname, fmt='%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S_{fname}'):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=fname)

shutil.move('c:\python34\y.log' , 'C:\python34\PyScript\y.log')

src = 'C:\PyScript\y.log'
dst = timeStamped('po.log')
os.rename(src , dst)
```

this the code I used but im getting error as:

```
    os.rename(src , dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\
PyScript\\y.log' -> '27-08-2014 12-24-48_po.log'
```

So Pls help me in this

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: It seems there's a typo in your `src` string. Shouldn't it be `src = 'C:\python34\PyScript\y.log'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that the filename is incorrect. Notice the `r''` to use the rawstring rather than escaped strings for the file paths.

Try this:

```
import shutil
import datetime
import os

def timeStamped(fname, fmt='%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S_{fname}'):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=fname)

shutil.move('c:\python34\y.log' , 'C:\python34\PyScript\y.log')

src = r'C:\python34\PyScript\y.log'
dst = timeStamped('po.log')
dst = os.path.join(r'C:\python34\PyScript', dst)
os.rename(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
import shutil
import datetime
import os

src = 'c:\python34\y.log'
dst = 'c:\PyScript\y.log'
rnm = 'po.log'

def timeStamped(fname, fmt='%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S_{fname}'):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=fname)

shutil.move(src, dst)
rnm = timeStamped(rnm)
os.rename(dst, os.path.dirname(dst) + '\\' + rnm)
```

Result is:

```
c:\PyScript\27-08-2014 12-13-09_po.log
```